# Why is the Kanji 「太」read 「ふとし]?

Tags: kanji, manga

I found this one from a title of a manga [チャンピオン太](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E5%A4%AA)

As my understanding, it should be read just as「ふと」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So-called i-adjectives in Modern Japanese used to end with *-shi* in Classical period. Some boy's names still retain those old forms, such as たかし, さとし, つよし, やすし, ひろし or ふとし (conversely, they wouldn't name their boys in Modern adjective forms like たかい, さとい, つよい etc).

There's one more thing that Japanese names often contain some "unordinary" kun'yomi of kanji that might beyond your imagination. They also derives from obsolete readings in olden times now mostly confined within personal or proper names (名乗【なの】り). For example:

> たかし: 高, 喬, 崇, 貴, 隆, 尭, 敬, ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might just be a person name. One of the readings of 太 is indeed ふとし when used as a proper name.

Look [here](http://name.m3q.jp/list?g=&s=%E3%81%B5%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97) for example.

Comment: There is no might. It is a person's name (nickname to be more precise). From the link in OP's post: スポーツ万能の少年・大東太（だいとう ふとし）が力道山に弟子入りしチャンピオンを目指す。