# 一代 pronounced as かずよ？

Tags: kanji, names

I saw the following example sentence on [WaniKani](https://www.wanikani.com):

あそこに立っている外人の男の人のとなりにいる女の人があのゆう名なまつい一代さんです。

*The lady next to the foreign guy standing over there is THE famous Kazuyo Matsui.*

The part I'm confused about is the name at the end: まつい一代さんです。

From what I've learned I would pronounce 一代　as ichidai (lifetime). I've not ever seen either 一 or 代 pronounced in this way (kazuyo) before.

If there's not some other trick going on, how is かずよ divided among the two kanji?

Comment: See here for the couple of dozen readings of the kanji 「一」: https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80

Comment: This even directly refers to one of the characters from your example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_name#Difficulty_of_reading_names

Comment: See also [Which readings would you use to pronounce people's names?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5529/78).

Comment: `how is かずよ divided among the two kanji` -- It's [一]{かず}+[代]{よ}... Did you look up the readings of these kanji in any (online) kanji dictionary, or maybe Wiktionary, before asking here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which readings would you use to pronounce people's names?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/which-readings-would-you-use-to-pronounce-peoples-names)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35814/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2553/7810